# Azure container copy only changes

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage, azure-static-web-app

I would like to update static website assets from github repos. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-static-site-github-actions) suggests to use an action based on

```
az storage blob upload-batch --account-name <STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME> -d '$web' -s .
```

If I see this correct, this copies all files regardless of the changes. Even if only one file was altered. Is it possible to only transfer files that have been changed? Like rsync does.

Else I would try to judge the changed files based on the git history and only transfer them. Please also answer, if you know an existing solution in this direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the sugggestion by @4c74356b41, I discovered that the mentioned tool was recently integrated into the az tool.

It can be used the same way as `az storage blob upload-batch`. The base command is:
[`az storage blob sync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az_storage_blob_sync)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `azcopy sync` to achieve that. That is a different tool, though.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs-synchronize?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-sync